# How can I prevent values from being passed into a list in the incorrect order, and seemingly random numbers being attached to each value?

Tags: python, csv

Hey stackoverflow community!

I'm trying to write a program that can read data from a file, and return specific number values in the form of a .csv file to be read into excel for later usage. My code seems to be able to read the data and return the desired values fine, but when it begins to populate a list things get messed up.

Is there something in my code that's automatically generating the undesired add-ons? Help on this would be appreciated!

I'm currently using python 2.7

I've tried downloading a pip installer to download the xlwt library, but I have not been able download it at all. In my current code, I tried to make '\n' my delimiter to remove that from the output, but it didn't really make much of a difference for me.

```py
import os
import csv

os.chdir(r'fileLocation')
# location = str(input("Enter the location of the file: "))
x = {}
y = {}
z = {}

i = 1
with open('fileName.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Location in file of desired data' in line:
            for line in f:
                if 'Height: ' in line:
                    a = line
                    a = a.replace('Height: ', '')
                    x[i] = a
                    print x[i]

                if 'X: ' in line:
                    a = line
                    a = a.replace('X: ', '')
                    y[i] = a
                    print y[i]

                if 'Y: ' in line:
                    a = line
                    a = a.replace('Y: ', '')
                    z[i] = a
                    print z[i]

                i = i + 1
s = [(x), (y), (z)]
print(s)

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = '\n', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows([s])
```

I would like my output list to look like `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`, but in between reading and populating my list becomes jumbled - it looks more like `[{204: '2\n' 1: '3\n' 201: '1\n'; 203: '2\n' 12: '3\n' 201: '1\n'; 24: '2\n' 51: '3\n' 1: '1\n'}]`.

Comment: For installing, `xlwt` what command did you try? Maybe this should be another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `z` are declared as [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with their declaration with `{}` and the use `x[i]=a`. In this case, `i` is the number of the csv line. You can declare a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) before reading the file.

You have `\n` in your final print because you don't convert the result. This can be done with `int()` function

If you want to have `s` equals to `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, you only have to do this:

```py
import os
import csv

os.chdir(r'fileLocation')
# location = str(input("Enter the location of the file: "))

x = []
y = []
z = []
with open('fileName.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Location in file of desired data' in line:
            for line in f:
                if 'Height: ' in line:
                    x.append(float(line.replace('Height: ', '')))
                    print a

                if 'X: ' in line:
                    y.append(float(line.replace('X: ', '')))
                    print a

                if 'Y: ' in line:
                    z.append(float(line.replace('Y: ', '')))
                    print a
s = [x, y, z]
print(s)

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = '\n', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows([s])
```

*edit*: replace `int()` with `float()` because there are float values in the csv.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm receiving the following error when I apply the suggested changes "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-0.855000\n' ". I think I should've stated the data looked more like - 0.00321 rather than discrete values, my apologies. Would I just replace "int()" with "float()"?

Comment: Yes, `float` replacing `int` will work. I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for this as I missed it in my original question, but I was hoping to have the output be a 2D list that looked like [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]. Whereas this is returning [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]. Could you tell me how I can go about achieving this?

Comment: Then, you create three lists not dict. I also edit my answer.